# What is the advantage of rectangular arrays over jagged arrays if they are slower?

Tags: c#

In Java there are no rectangular arrays, there's only one way to make a multidimensional array, example: `int[][] a = new int[10][10];`.

In C#, you can't do that and it's only possible to declare and define sizes of all dimensions in one statement by using the rectangular array: `int[,] a = new int[10,10];` or having to write this monstrosity:

`new int[10][] {new int[10], new int[10],new int[10],new int[10],new int[10],new int[10],new int[10],new int[10],new int[10],new int[10]}`.

But, rectangular arrays are slower when you access their elements, so, my question is, what is their advantage then? Why didn't the C# language developers just go with the Java approach?

I understand that the memory for the rectangular array will be allocated in a contiguous block, but I don't understand the advantage of that either.

Comment: @Coder-Man - I downvoted because the premise of your question is not correct (`"it's only possible to declare and define sizes of all dimensions in one statement by using the rectangular array"`) and obvious by searching for jagged array examples.

Comment: No language is an island by its own, although Java tried harder, multi-dimensional arrays are quite common in other runtime environments.  COM in particular, .NET was meant to provide an alternative but still being compatible with it.

Comment: @Coder-Man - Just because your *invented* syntax is incorrect, does not mean it's not doable. Did you try something like `int[][] a = new int[10][];`? If you notice, I **did not**  define the size of the other dimension - hence the ability "jagged-ness"'.

Comment: @Coder-Man: Then initialize them *in the statement...* `int[][] a = new int[1][] { new int[2] };` (first dimension size of 1 used for simplicity). I'm also slightly confused as to how that Java array is not rectangular, but I don't have much Java experience, so forget it, that's not the point...

Comment: Some of the advantages of rectangular arrays are the contiguousness of the memory, a slight advantage in moving up and down a column (offset memory by width*sizeof(element)), easier initialization, and a better matching of the syntax to the semantics in certain circumstances (if you are working with a matrix, why not have the code you use look like you are working with a matrix).

Comment: _"rectangular arrays are slower when you access their elements"_ you did not provide a reference for that. Also: If it is true, then are they so much slower that it matters to you / your requirements? Sometimes code cleanliness / readability is more important than speed.

Comment: Not trying to contribute to the mud-throwing, but one of these references claims "if you’re accessing the array randomly, a jagged array can be 33% slower than a rectangular array." (https://blog.mischel.com/2013/05/08/are-jagged-arrays-faster-than-rectangular-arrays/)

Answer (score 1):

.NET itself supports both rectangular and jagged arrays. It was up to each language whether it exposed easy syntax for one or both of these concepts<sup>1</sup>.

Visual Basic (classic) supported rectangular arrays but had no first class support for jagged arrays.

In early C#, it was anticipated that a lot of code would either interoperate with VB code using rectangular arrays (or, well, COM in general as Hans already commented) or would themselves be code translated from VB. So you would want C# to *support* such arrays easily.

And honestly, we shouldn't be picking our data structures based *purely* on which we believe will absolutely "perform best". There are often plenty of other decisions that will lead us towards picking a rectangular array over a jagged array. I.e. knowing that what we've got really does represent a rectangular data set can make our own logic simpler. A simpler to reason about *algorithm* in a non-critical path is often a big benefit.

And these days, if we're not implementing collection classes ourselves, we shouldn't be looking at arrays first anyway.

---

<sup>1</sup>Similarly, it exposes arrays with a lower bound that isn't `0`. No easy syntax for that in C#.